# How to show/hide elements using media query?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

By using media query I would like to show the last element of the following list (2) when the screen width is above 768px.

Here is the [jsfiddle like](http://jsfiddle.net/fengelz/yyQ5u/).
Here is the basic css code (1).

---

(1)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .menu li.hide{    
        visibility: none;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .menu li.hide{    
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

---

(2)

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>One</li>
    <li class='hide'>Nine</li>
</ul>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyQ5u/19/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body{
        background:#030;
    }
    .menu li{    
        font:12px Verdana;    
        width:100px;
        padding-left:10px;
    }
    .menu li:last-child{    
        display: none
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    body{
        background: honeydew;
    }
    .menu li{    
        font:22px Verdana;    
        width:200px;
        padding-left:20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the min and max width on the media query:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yyQ5u/28/

It looks like the main problem was with the order of things and the actual media queries. I put your non-conditional CSS at the top of the CSS pane and the media queries below.

Then I tweaked the media queries which seemed to sort of cover each other:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
```

and

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
```